# Calculate the average on runtime from the query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, raw-query-builder

I want to calculate the average of daily gc_score obtained from the below query:

```php
$query = DB::table('qc_feedbacks')
    ->selectRaw("
        COUNT(cru_agent_detail_id) as numberofEvaluations,
        COUNT( CASE WHEN qc_feedbacks.status='Passed' Then 1 ELSE Null End) as passed,
        COUNT( CASE WHEN qc_feedbacks.status!='Passed' Then 1 ELSE Null End) as failed,
        AVG(score) as gc_score,
        cru_agent_details.cru_id as cru_id,
        cru_agent_details.name as agentName,
        cru_agent_details.team_lead as team_lead,
        evaulated_by,
        cru_agent_detail_id,
        audit_date
    ")
    ->join('cru_agent_details', 'cru_agent_details.id', '=', 'qc_feedbacks.cru_agent_detail_id')
    ->groupBy('audit_date', 'cru_agent_detail_id')
    ->orderBy('audit_date', 'desc');
```

The average of daily gc_score obtained from the above query is our monthly gc_score. The above query should be displaying month wise gc_score for the agent by averaging the gc_score from the above query and combine it to monthwise. Below is attached example of how to obtain the monthly gc_score from the daily gc score:

| Agent | Daily gc_score | No of audits | No of Passed | No of Failed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 75 | 20 | 15 | 5 |
| A1 | 85 | 20 | 17 | 3 |

Now I want to convert my above query code in such a way that it takes the average of daily gc_score column and give a monthly gc_score per agent. For instance, the monthly gc_score will be obtained by:
(75+85)/2 = 80
And the final possible outcome will be:

| Agent | Monthly gc_score |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 80 |

I am wondering how can I obtain this? I have tried with following code:

```php
$query = DB::table('qc_feedbacks')
    ->selectRaw("
        COUNT(cru_agent_detail_id) as numberofEvaluations,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN qc_feedbacks.status='Passed' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS passed,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN qc_feedbacks.status!='Passed' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS failed,
        AVG(score) AS gc_score,
        cru_agent_details.cru_id AS cru_id,
        cru_agent_details.name AS agentName,
        cru_agent_details.team_lead AS team_lead,
        cru_agent_detail_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(audit_date, '%Y-%m') AS month
    ")
    ->join('cru_agent_details', 'cru_agent_details.id', '=', 'qc_feedbacks.cru_agent_detail_id')
    ->groupBy('month', 'cru_agent_detail_id')
    ->orderBy('month', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first query, you can make it as a sub query and then select the avg(gc_score) of it.

Otherwise, you could group by month date:

```
->groupByRaw('MONTH(audit_date)');
```